# Xamarin UI testing - preinstalled apk

Tags: xamarin, testing, xamarin.uitest

There is an apk installed on the emulator manually. I want to start testing this application. You cannot reinstall it using `Xamarin UI Tests`. `AppInitializer.cs` contains :

```
string keyStore = @"C:\...\Certificate\Mycompany.keystore";
return ConfigureApp
.Android
.InstalledApp("com.myapk.test")
.PreferIdeSettings()
.KeyStore(
       keyStore,
       "passw", 
       "passw",
       "\"alias\"")
.EnableLocalScreenshots()
.StartApp();
```

When I run the test through Test Explorer, I catch the Exception:

```
System.Exception : Failed to execute: C:\Program Files\Android\jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25\bin\jarsigner.exe -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -signedjar "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\uitest\a-287A94...D0807\23248\SignedTestServer.apk" -storepass passw -keypass passw -keystore "C:\...\Certificate\Mycompany.keystore" "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\uitest\a-287A...D0807\TestServer.apk" ""alias"" - exit code: 1
Only one alias can be specified

Please type jarsigner -help for usage
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've just executed it manually :

> jarsigner.exe -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -signedjar "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\uitest\a-287A94...D0807\23248\SignedTestServer.apk" -storepass passw -keypass passw -keystore "C:...\Certificate\Mycompany.keystore" "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\uitest\a-287A...D0807\TestServer.apk" "alias"

After that I got a new apk file called `SignedTestServer.apk`. I've copied it into folder :

> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\uitest\a-287A943C412ED6ED5DEB1675E7FDF91843FD0807

and rerun tests.